# How do I enable a two-column view in lotus notes mail?

Tags: lotus-notes

Does anyone know how I can enable a two-column view of the e-mail in Lotus Notes 8.x?

By two-column view I mean that the first column contains the list of e-mails and the second one shows the e-mail content itself (similar to Outlook)?

Cheers!

Jack

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Notes 8.5, the bar along the top of the mail list view (that contains New, Reply...) on the far right has Show drop down where you can choose to see the preview on the side.